# USB hub busy when mining Peercoin with Red Fury ASIC running Minepeon

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, asic, peercoin

I have a RasPI running minepeon 0.2.5, a [DLINK USB Hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008VFAF) and a Red Fury USB ASIC Bitcoin Miner 2.2-2.7GH/Sec By BITFURY

I've added my pool https://ppcoin.d7.lt/ and things looked good except nothing is mining.

The miner states it's running but the device id is 0 and hashrate is 0.

I've tried to start the miner manually in accordance to https://ppcoin.d7.lt/getting-started

```
cgminer -o stratum+tcp://stratum.d7.lt:3333 -u miner.1 -p 99999
```

It starts up but states that the USB hub is busy, I see it testing the Red Fury but after that it still is not mining.

Am I missing something?

Related Posts:

- http://www.peercointalk.org/index.php?topic=499.msg17709#msg17709
- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=251675.msg4841184#msg4841184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue helped me solve my issue:

- https://github.com/MineForeman/minepeon-base/issues/13#issuecomment-33760864

running the command

```
sudo lsusb -v
```

I get this out put, is this correct?

```
idVendor 0x03eb Atmel Corp.
idProduct 0x204b LUFA USB to Serial Adapter Project
bcdDevice 0.00
iManufacturer 1 BFMG
iProduct 2 Bitfury BF1
```

add the lines below to this file

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/01-miner.rules
```

add these lines

```
# BF1
ATTRS{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="204b", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", MODE="0666", GROUP="minepeon"
```

rebooted the server and now I see my miner!